# Consider the vector space of all $n\times n$matrices over $\mathbb{R} $and let $W$={$B^{t}AB$}, B is orthogonal then prove the following

Tags: linear-algebra

Let n be an integer $ \geq 2$ and let $ M_n (\mathbb{R}) $ denote the vector space of $n\times n $ real  matrices .Let $ B\in M_n (\mathbb{R}) $ be an orthogonal matrix and and let $ B^t $denote the transpose of $ B $.Consider $W$ $=$ {$ B^{t}AB : A\in M_n (\mathbb{R}) $} then show that $ W $ $=$ $M_n (\mathbb{R}) $.

very easy If I consider $B $ is the identity matrix, because then the elements in the standard ordered basis of $M_n (\mathbb{R}) $ is in $ W $ . But  no clue  if $B $ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix .

Please give me a little hint. Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the orthogonal matrices $B, B^{t}$ have inverses? Try showing $M_n ( \Bbb R) \subseteq W$.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said , sorry,  and I couldn't understand how to show  $ M_n (\mathbb{R}) $ is a subset of $W $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $B$ is orthogonal iff $B^TB=I$ (iff $\exists B^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}=B^T$).

Then, any $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ can be written as
$$A=IAI=(B^TB)A(B^TB)=B^T(BAB^T)B$$